# Laravel exception not catching

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to do a very basic exception try catch, but it doesn't catch.

```
 $id =0;
 try {
        $question = $this->model->find($id);  // will not find anything since $id = 0
        $question->delete(); // throw an exception
        return true;
 } catch (\Exception $e) {
        dd ('hello');  // should end up here, but no?!?!? 
 } catch (FatalThrowableError $f) {
        echo ("fatal"); // or here... but no. 
 }
```

but the catch doesn't "catch". I get an Fatal error in the browser saying that delete was called on a null object. But that's exactly what I was trying to do: do a delete on a null object (id = 0 is not in the DB), to test the exception.

I have tried

```
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError;
```

or simply

```
Exception;
FatalThrowableError;
```

Also, having the \Exception $e  or Exception $e (with or without ) doesn't change anything.

Note that if I add a line like  $foo = 4/0    I get into the Exception section (dd (hello)).

in .env   APP_DEBUG=true, APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug

I'm on Laravel 5.5 using PHP 7.0.10 on windows 7.

Comment: I would add the exact contents of the error message you are seeing. Also, have you tried catching `\Throwable` ? This was added in PHP 7 to replace `\Exception` - http://php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php

Comment: just found the following https://www.codecourse.com/forum/topics/laravel-catch-a-fatal-throwable-error

Answer (score 15, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php

> As the `Error` hierarchy does not inherit from `Exception`, code that uses
>   `catch (Exception $e) { ... }` blocks to handle uncaught exceptions in
>   PHP 5 will find that these `Errors` are not caught by these blocks.
>   Either a `catch (Error $e) { ... }` block or a `set_exception_handler()`
>   handler is required.

You can, additionally, `catch (\Throwable $e) {}` to account for both `Error` and `Exception` types.